# Problems creating regex for not containing character

Tags: swift, swift-regexbuilder

I want to act on markdown strings depending on whether they start with one, two or no `#`, but I am failing to rule `##` out for being recognized as a title:

```swift
let strings = ["# Fancy Title", "## Fancy Subtitle", "Body Content")
for string in strings {
  if string.contains(/^#(^#)/) { //string should only contain **one** #, but `strings[0]` falls through now …
    // parse title
  } else if string.contains(/^##/) {
    // parse subtitle
  } else {
    // parse body
  }
}
```

How do I properly exclude `##` in my first `if` stmt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check for `#` followed by anything that isn't another `#`. That would be:

```
/^#[^#]/
```

You wanted square brackets, not parentheses.

---

There's really no need for the regular expressions. You could use:

```swift
if string.hasPrefix("##") {
    // parse subtitle
} else if string.hasPrefix("#") {
    // parse title
} else {
    // parse body
}
```

Note that you want to check for `##` before you check for `#`.

Or with simpler regular expressions:

```swift
if string.contains(/^##/) {
    // parse subtitle
} else if string.contains(/^#/) {
    // parse title
} else {
    // parse body
}
```

Comment: Funny enough, `/^#[^#]/` does not work as expected–but you are right in pointing out that `.hasPrefix` is the much better approach in my use case. Thanks

Comment: @appfrosch `/^#[^#]/` does work. I tested it using your exact code with that small change and it gives the desired result. But the other solutions are simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
if string.contains(/^#[^#]/) {
```